# Removing items of on list based on another list

Tags: python, list

How to remove items from list `lst1` based on list `lst2`?

```
lst1 = ['abc__2','def__3','xyz__3','pqr__1']
lst2 = ['def','xyz','tuv']
```

for splitting I did

```
lst3 = [k.split("__")[0] for k in lst1]
```

for removing I did

```
new_list = [i for i in lst3 if i not in lst2]
```

But in this way, I lost the originality of the original list.

Required list:  `new_list = ['abc__2','pqr__1']`

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays. Please fix that and your formatting. The question is very messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating `arr3` with the splited values you can split them in the `if` when creating `new_arr`

```
arr1 = ['abc__2', 'def__3', 'xyz__3', 'pqr__1']
arr2 = ['def', 'xyz', 'tuv']
new_arr = [i for i in arr1 if i.split("__")[0] not in arr2]
print(new_arr) # ['abc__2', 'pqr__1']
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use an `re.search` regex approach here to examine each item in the first array, with the help of an alternation:

```py
arr1 = ['abc__2','def__3','xyz__3','pqr__1']
arr2 = ['def','xyz','tuv']
regex = r'^(?:' + r'|'.join(arr2) + r')'

output = [x for x in arr1 if not re.search(regex, x)]
print(output)  # ['abc__2', 'pqr__1']
```

By the way, the regex pattern being used here is:

```regex
^(?:def|xyz|tuv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn `arr2` into a `set` for fast lookup:

```
s2 = set(arr2)
```

Then filter based on containment similarly to what you attempted, but without creating the additional list:

```
[x for x in arr1 if x.split('___')[0] not in s2]
```

To use the intermediary list `arr3`, you would have to keep it to the original somehow. One way would be indices:

```
[arr[i] for i, x in enumerate(arr3) if x not in s2]
```

Another is to make `arr3` into a dictionary instead of a list:

```
d3 = {x: x.split('___')[0] for x in arr}
[v for k, v in d3.items() if k not in s2]
```

Comment: Hey, small correction, ```x.split('__')[0]``` you have kept three underscores.

Comment: @Random_Pythoneer59. Should be fixed now. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
arr1 = ['abc__2', 'def__3', 'xyz__3', 'pqr__1']
arr2 = ['def', 'xyz', 'tuv']

new_arr = arr1.copy() #New copy of the arr1
for item in arr1:
    for item2 in arr2:
        if item.startswith(item2):
            new_arr.remove(item)

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
print(new_arr)
```

Output:

```
['abc__2', 'def__3', 'xyz__3', 'pqr__1']
['def', 'xyz', 'tuv']
['abc__2', 'pqr__1']
```

Comment: Probably use `startswith` instead of `__contains__` here

Comment: @Mad Physicist Yes, thats better